# Android: Singleton which is used between Activity and Service

Tags: android, singleton

im wondering if it would be a bad idea to create a Singleton that is used between some Android Activities and a Android Service. As far as I know the static fields, in my case the Singleton, is available as long as the whole Process is alive.

My plan is to use a singleton instead of Parcelable to share data between my activities and a Background service. So my Activity1 will add some data by calling MySingleton.getInstance().addData(foo); then I would sent an Intent to inform my Service that new Data has been added to the singleton. Next my BackgroundService would handle the intent and call MySingleton.getInstance().getLatestData(); then it would process the data (takes some time). The result of the service would next be "post" back by using the singleton and fire a broadcast intent, which are handled by the Activity1 (if alive) and the Activity1 will retrieve the result  from the singleton.

Do you guys think thats a bad idea?

EDIT:
What I want to implement is an peace of software that downloads data from a web server parse it and return the result. So my Activity would create DownloadJob Object. The DownloadJob-Object would be put into the DownloadScheduler (Singleton) which queues and manage all DownloadJobs. The DownloadScheduler would allow to run 5 DownloadJobs at the same time and use a queue to store the waiting. The effective Download would be done by the DownloadService (IntentService), which gets informed over an Intent that the a new DownloadJob should now be executed (downloaded) right now. The DowanlodService would retrieve the next job from the DownloadSchedulers queue (PriorityBlockingQueue) and return the Result by setting DownloadJob.setResult(...) and fires up an broadcast intent, that the Result is ready, which will be received by the DownloadScheduler which would remve the job from the queue and inform the Activity that the download is complete etc.

So in my scenario I would use the singleton to access the DownloadJobs from the DownloadService instead of making a DownloadJob Parcelable and pass it with the Intent. So i would avoid the problem, that I have two DownloadJobs in memory (one on the "Activity Site" and one on "Service site").

Any suggestions how to solve this better?

Is it true that static instances, like DownloadScheduler(Singleton), would be used by freed by the android system on low memory? So would subclassing the Application and hold there the reference (non static) avoid this problem?

Comment: Yes, it's a bad idea, in Android your process can die at any time, keep your data in some persistent store and then write a content provider as an interface to it.

Comment: I do not net to store the data persistent. I simply need some kind of queue where Activitis put some objects in, the Service retrieve them and do some work and then return the result ...

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the singleton *just* as shared memory between a background service which I assume is performing operations on a different thread, you may run into synchronization issues and or read inconsistent data.

If the data in the singleton is not synchronized, you have to be careful because you are relying on your "protocol" to be sure that nobody is reading while your background thread is writing (which may lead to errors).

On the other hand, if it is synchronized, you are risking to face anr error because the activity which reads the data may be blocked waiting the service to finish to write the data in the singleton.

As the other said, you also have to keep in mind that your singleton may be freed if the os needs resources, and that your data may not be there anymore.

I'd rather use an event bus such as [otto](http://square.github.com/otto/) or [eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

EDIT:

Using a singleton as the entry point of background (intent) service is the approach suggested in 2010 Virgil Dobjanschi [talk](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html) about building rest client applications for android.

The suggested approach is having a singleton that performs as controller of ongoing requests. Please consider also that request to intent service are already queued by the os, so you can throw several intents that will be processed sequentially by the intent service.

Some time ago I also tried take that as a starting point for a library, which still remains unfinished. YOu can find the sources [here](https://github.com/fedepaol/PostmanLib--Rings-Twice--Android)

What I would certainly not do is to store your data in the singleton. The approach I would prefer is to store the data in some persistent storage (such as sql / preferences / file / content provider) and let the client know of the change through a broadcast message (or, if you are using a content provider, through an observer).

Finally, to some extent this is the approach followed by the [robospice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) library, which looks quite mature and ships a lot of interesting features such as caching.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have added a concrete scenario to my post. An EventBus seems to be a good solution. Have you experience with the EventBus and do you know what would perform better(EventBus or Intent)?

Comment: I modified the answer. I've never tried evenbus but given your clarification I'd go for robospice.

Answer (score 1):

A better idea is to subclass Application and put any long living objects in there.  By subclassing Application you can properly handle startup and shutdown of the application something you can't easily do with a singleton.  Also by using an Application Activites and Services can share access to the models within your program without resorting to parcelables.  And you can avoid all of the problems Singletons bring to your program.

You also don't have to resort to storing everything in a database which requires lots of boiler plate code just to shove a bunch of data in there.  It doesn't do anything for sharing behavior between parts of your application and doesn't do anything to facilitate communication and centralization of activities.  If you really need to persist state between shutdowns great use it, but if not you can save yourself a lot of work.

You could also look into using something like [Roboguice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/) which makes injecting shared models into your Activities and services.

You might find this helpful:

[what's design pattern principle in the Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235380/whats-design-pattern-principle-in-the-android-development/4329537#4329537)

Comment: subclassing application is a good. So do you think i should use an "normal" reference in the subclassed Application instead of a singleton? Btw. I have added a concrete scenario to my post.

Comment: If you are building a download manager then you should NOT use a singleton. You really should never ever use a singleton, but especially for a download manager. For one if you run into a situation where Android wants to shutdown your application you will know it because the Application receives a callback. If this happens you can properly shutdown each thread running in the background save off any data you'd need to restore. The code is simple to access the application:  MyApplication app = (MyApplication)activity.getApplication(). I'm not sure what you mean by "normal" reference.

Answer (score 0):

Using a singleton like this is not necessarily a bad idea, but you will lose it's state if Android decides to stop your process. You may want to consider storing your state instead in a SQLite database or a persistent queue (take a look at [tape](http://square.github.com/tape/) for a good example).

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but i don't need to persist any object. See my last edit on the previous post.