# Is it better to separate several coupled tasks into several coupled fragments instead of doing all work in one fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

*Sorry for my English.*

Is it good to separate several coupled tasks [ such as *loading data -> displaying data (or exception message with ability to reload data)* ] into several coupled fragments ?

Very often I have to do something like:

- do something long and get result (for example, load big data)
- if exception occurred, then display exception message and give the user ability to reload data (for example, simple button *Reload*)
- otherwise, display data

For example, in the *Google Play Store*.  At first there is some communication with server. If an android device is off the internet connection then displaying message about it and user giving the chance to reload data. Otherwise, displaying app content.

How I usually do in such cases.

In activity I have some container (usually one) for this and three different fragments (to do something long, to display result, to display exception).

To do something long I create `TaskFragment` with `setRetainInstance(true)` (in order not to handle *screen rotations* etc.)

If I get a result, then I replace `TaskFragment` with `ResultFragment` (in which I pass the result).

If I get an exception then I replace `TaskFragment` with `ExceptionFragment`. In `ExceptionFragment` I show exception description and simple button *Try again*. On click on this button I restart `TaskFragment` (replacing `ExceptionFragment` with `TaskFragment`).

I.e.

```
                        _result________ [ ResultFragment ]
                       |   
                       |           
                       |
                       |
_request______[ TaskFragment ]
               |       |
               |       |
               |       exception
               |       request
               |       |_______________ [ ExceptionFragment ]
               |                                     |
               |                                     |
               |___________________request___________|
```

Unfortunately I came to this experience recently. Before that I used one fragment to load and display loaded data. So I couldn't use `setRetaintInstance(true)`, because if I used it then I couldn't use different layouts for different device configurations (rotations, etc.). I even wrote complicated [fragment class managing screen rotations so not to interrupt AsyncTasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264609/fragment-capable-to-start-long-running-tasks-and-receive-results-even-after-conf?rq=1) which I used to load and to display loaded data.

Now, when I came to my new solution, I found it much better and easily than I used before. It also provides good decomposition of work.

What do you think about that? Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with this method. Having your data in a viewless Fragment is precisely what you want to do in either case. It has the advantage of keeping your data around beyond screen flips. You don't have to reload it if you were to detach your Fragment. It keeps your data inside your Activity so you don't have to bind to a Service.  It also keeps the logic to a Fragment class and away from your UI which increases long-term maintainability.

The only thing you may consider (again, it's up to your design) is to not have the TaskFragment handle anything UI related.  What this means is, instead of the TaskFragment adding `ExceptionFragment` or `ResultFragment`, you have the Activity handle it.  That way the `TaskFragment`'s only job is to handle the data. It would separate the UI logic from the data model class.  You can register callbacks to the `TaskFragment` that the Activity and Fragments can attach to in their respective `onResume()` methods then detach in `onPause()`